# When using the spoofed IP option with arping no replies are returned

Tags: networking, arp

```
Host IP: 10.0.0.21
Spoofed IP: 10.0.0.112
Live IP: 10.0.0.138
```

When I normally run arping like:

```
arping -c 1 -I wlan0 10.0.0.138
```

I receive a reply. However when I spoof the IP using a machine on the subnet which is not in use, I receive no replies.

```
arping -c 1 -U -s 10.0.0.112 -I wlan0 10.0.0.138
```

Why is that?
I have enabled forwarding on my machine.

I also had a look at the ARP request being sent using scapy, and it is identical except for the source IP addresses - a broadcast is sent out both times.

Another consideration is that my host IP has address 10.0.0.21. Could it be that a reply is actually being sent to 10.0.0.112?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you spoof an IP, the answer will go to that IP not to your IP so, either you put your ethernet card in promiscuous mode or you won't receive anything (by the way, in promisuous mode you won't receive an answer to the arping, but you can see the answered packets with tcpdump or whireshark).